# Python backslash in string evaluation

Tags: python

I am debugging my program and I am confused as to why one of my statements is evaluating to false. I am checking if the second to last index in my array (which is a string) starts with '\' character. I am writing an interpreter for post script and so this helps me determine whether or not the user is defining a variable ex: \x. My if statement that is checking this for me is evaluating to false and I cannot figure out why. Any thoughts?

```
def psDef():
   if(opstack[-2].startswith('\\')):   # this is evaluating to false for some reason
       name = opPop() #pop the name off the operand stack
       value = opPop() #pop the value off the operand stack
       define(name, value)
   else:
       print("Improper use of keyword: def")

def testLookup():
   opPush("\n1")
   opPush(3)
   psDef()
   if lookup("n1") != 3:
       return False
   return True
```

Comment: `"\n1"` does not start with a backslash. It starts with a newline character, represented in the string literal as `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

> The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as **newline**, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character.

`\n` means `ASCII Linefeed (LF)`.So to display a backslash in a string literal you need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

like `opPush("\\n1")`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@McGrady has already pointed out your error. If you change this line:

```
 opPush("\n1")
```

to something like:

```
 opPush("\\n1")
```

you'll probably get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

By default Python accepts backslash escape sequences in strings. `\n` becomes a newline.

To get an actual sequence of `\` and `n` you can use a double backslash: `'\\n'` or mark the string as "raw": `r'\n'`.